# javascript use await in my function call

Tags: javascript, async-await

Lets say I have a functin like:

```
function some(){
    console.log("wow")
    return "some"
}

var some_test = await some()
console.log(some_test)
```

I know it works without await but I want to test await . Here it gives `unexpected token` error.

Why I am unable to use await here ?

Comment: async action I guess. I am new to javascript

Comment: It is an ES7 functionlity. I believe browser doesnot support this functionlity yet.

Comment: How can I make some call wait for untill its finished

Comment: More info on await is here https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/

Comment: Starting to look like c#

Comment: I believe `await` can only be used inside a function declared `async` ... but I can't be sure

Comment: @JaromandaX that is true in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keywords `async` and `await` are available in `Node.js` applications and not yet supported for client side JavaScript. In order to use these keywords, your `Node.js` application needs to be using the ES7 standards. [Here's](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/) a nice introduction to the core concepts. Also, [here](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) is the official ECMAScript github repo that documents it.

The calling function must be marked as `async` and then another `async` method within that call can then be awaited using the `await` keyword, just like is done in `C#`. Examples of the syntax are found [here](http://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#async-function-definitions).

```
async function chainAnimationsAsync(elem, animations) {
        let ret = null;
        try {
            for(const anim of animations) {
                ret = await anim(elem);
            }
        } catch(e) { /* ignore and keep going */ }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: It won't work on old phones and in Internet Explorer.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions if your customers don't use either then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Async functions are supported in the latest versions of Chrome and FF already, and according to caniuse, in the upcoming Edge 15. The `await` keyword can only be used inside a function marked with `async`. A couple of good tutorials on the subject:

[Async Function Documentation from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

[Introduction to Async Functions](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/intro-javascript-async-functions.shtml)